# How to allocate a pseudo-tty in which to run scripts from IDE?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, terminal, console, pycharm

Eclipse (and other IDEs, such as Pycharm/IntelliJ), don't seem to use a proper terminal with which to run programs. This can lead to some problems when a program needs to work with a proper stdin/stdout.

For example, the simple python script

```
# Exit upon any keypress

import sys
import termios
import tty

fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())

while not sys.stdin.read(1):
    pass
```

Will function perfectly when run directly from bash, but will fail with the following error when from from any IDE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anishmoorthy/Code/termserver/turst.py", line 19, in <module>
    while readchar() is None:
  File "/Users/anishmoorthy/Code/termserver/turst.py", line 10, in readchar
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tty.py", line 20, in setraw
    mode = tcgetattr(fd)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

More generally, any calls to `tcgetattr(<stdin>)` will fail.

I was wondering if there were any plugins or settings, Eclipse or IntelliJ, which would fix these errors by running scripts in a proper bash process.

IntelliJ actually has an ."Emulate terminal in output console" checkbox in its run configuration options which fixes these errors, but for some reason it doesn't register my enter key- making it more or less useless

Answer (score 3):

For IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm there is a hidden option that can be enabled by adding

```
-Drun.processes.with.pty=true
```

in `Help` | **Edit Custom VM Options**.

[See here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19938) for the related request.

Comment: This prevents the error from occurring, so I'll mark this the answer. However, this option seems to enable some sort of linebuffering. The script I posted will detect a keypress immediately when run through bash but, when run through pycharm, you actually have to press enter in order to dispatch your input (whereupon the script actually detects two keypresses). I don't suppose you know of any other way to disable this new behavior?

Comment: The better way would be to use the real Terminal. You can set up an external tool and bind it to some keyboard shortcut that will run the active editor script in the external terminal window. See also [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6701).