# Pycharm os.get_terminal_size() not working

Tags: module, operating-system, pycharm, python-3.7

Python 3.7.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Using Pycharm version:

```
PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-191.7479.30, built on May 30, 2019
Linux 4.18.0-22-generic
```

I'm having issues with the `os.get_terminal_size()` function call

Running the command from the terminal window works:

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.get_terminal_size()
os.terminal_size(columns=223, lines=18)
```

But running it from the Python Console window doesn't

```
>>>import os
>>>os.get_terminal_size()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

My googling hasn't produced much information specific to my issue at hand. What does `OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device` actually mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your implementation of Python relies on the terminal being compliant to the request for the terminal size by the OS. In the [CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c#L12057), the system call in `ioctl()` will fail because the device (terminal) doesn't recognize the command. You can try to set

```
-Drun.processes.with.pty=true
```

in `Help/Edit Custom VM Options...` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44852103/11713392) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `os` you can use `shutil`. This works without any hitch in Pycharm (and hopefully, by extension, IntelliJ).

```
import shutil
terminal_size = shutil.get_terminal_size(fallback=(120, 50))
# attributes
print('cols=', terminal_size.columns)
print('rows=', terminal_size.rows)
```